# An after-build copy command compatible with Windows and Linux at the same time

Tags: mono, copy, monodevelop

I'm developing C# using Mono and MonoDevelop in Windows and Ubuntu. I might code the same project in Windows today and tomorrow in Ubuntu (which is why I chose Mono and MonoDevelop).

In project properties I need to add some `After Build` commands to copy some projects compiled files into some alternate folders. And I've done this like so:

```
cp ${TargetFile} ${SolutionDir}/SomePorject/bin/${ProjectConfigName}/Plugins
```

While this command works perfectly in my Ubuntu machine, each time I'm using Windows my `Build` requests get canceled since this command can not be executed in Windows (there's no `cp` in Windows). It makes this a pain to switch between Ubuntu and Windows since each time I need to change these commands.

Now my question is, is there a copy command which works in Windows and Ubuntu alike? Or maybe MonoDevelop has come up with a copy command of its own which works according to the OS it is running under!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "configurations" is your way to go.

Create separate configurations for each platform (Right click on solution -> options -> configurations). After that, in "Custom commands" create two "After Build" commands, one for Windows, and other for Ubuntu.

When you build solution just choose your platform from your configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You could install cygwin on your Windows box.

Comment: That's a little overkill, don't you think?